# Add / Update context from macro

Tags: templating, macro

I'm trying to update the context from within a macro. Is this possible at all? I'm pretty close with the below code.

The var_dump within the below function shows the updated context. But when doing a `{{ dump(_context|keys) }}` after the macro call the context is unchanged.

Any ideas, much appreciated.

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

class TwiggedTwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
  public function getName()
  {
    return 'Twigged';
  }

  public function getFunctions()
  {
    return array(
      'addVar' => new \Twig_SimpleFunction('addVar', array($this, 'addVar'), array('needs_context' => true)),
    );
  }

  public function addVar($context, $str, $val)
  {
    $context['context'][$str] = $val;
    var_dump(array_keys($context['context']));
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you referring to a macro as defined with `{% macro %}` or this custom Twig Extension? If you're referring to an extension, I recommend going to StackOverflow as they will have more twig-related answers than we will.

Comment: Even calling the function in the template without the macro like so `{{ addVar('hello', 'world') }}` results in the same. I have also tried passing context by reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I took another approach to my problem and ended up creating a plugin variable allowing me to set data inside a macro and have it accessible in the template. It's not complicated and does the trick.

```
class MyPluginVariable
{
  /**
   * Store data for use within both
   * templates and macros. Easy way around
   * macros having their own context
   * @var [Array]
   */
  private static $store = [];

  /**
   * Set data in storage array
   * @param [String] $key
   * @param $value
   */
  public function set($key, $value) {
    self::$store[$key] = $value;
  }

  /**
   * Retrieve data from storage array
   * @param  [String] $key
   */
  public function get($key) {
    return self::$store[$key];
  }
}
```

To set data you simply call `{% do craft.MyPlugin.set('myVar', true) %}` and to retrieve it `{% set myVar = craft.MyPlugin.get('myVar') %}`

Answer (score 1):

From a quick glance, I don't think this is possible. In that function, the context is being passed in by value, not reference... So any changes are only to the local scope.

Comment: Thanks @jeremy. I've also tried passing it in by reference with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You were close with the extension… here's a function that sets the context by reference:

```php
namespace mytikilife\twig;

use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;

class MyExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    public function getFunctions(): array
    {
        return [
            new \Twig\TwigFunction('set_context_defaults', [$this, 'setContextDefaults'], ['needs_context' => true]),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param $context
     * @param $defaults
     */
    public function setContextDefaults(array &$context, array $defaults) {
        foreach($defaults as $key => $value) {
            if(!isset($context[$key])) {
                $context[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The trick is to add `['needs_context' => true]` to the `getFunction` return value.

You can then use it in templates like this:

```
{% do set_context_defaults({
    entry: entry,
    heading_html: 'Trading Post',
    heading_tag: 'h2',
    with_heading: true,
    lazy: craft.app.request.getParam('lazy', false),
    lazy_url: url(entry.url ~ '/trading-post', { lazy: false }),
    id: 'tiki-mugs-'~ entry.id ~'-trading-post'
}) %}
```